# finding values in dictionary based on their key

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to find the values of keys based on their 3 first letters. I have three different categories of subjects that i have to get the grade from, stored as value with the subject being key. I have ECO, GEO, and INF. As there are multiple subjects i want to get the values from every key containing either ECO, GEO or INF.

```py
subject={"INFO100":"A"}
    
(subject.get("INF"))
```

In this method i don't get the value, i have to use the whole Key. Is there a work-a-round? I want the values seperately so i can calculate their GPA based on their field of study:)

Comment: This is not directly possible without looping over the keys. Also this would defeat the purpose of a dictionary that has unique keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate on the pairs, to filter on the key and keep the value

```
subject = {"INFO100": "A", "INF0200": "B", "ECO1": "C"}

grades_inf = [v for k, v in subject.items() if k.startswith("INF")]
print(grades_inf)  # ['A', 'B']

grades_eco = [v for k, v in subject.items() if k.startswith("ECO")]
print(grades_eco)  # ['C']
```

Comment: You should probably include a note to mention that this is not efficient compared to direct mapping of keys in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

A said in the comments, the purpose of a dictionary is to have unique keys. Indexing is extremely fast as it uses hash tables. By searching for parts of the keys you need to loop and lose the benefit of hashing.

Why don't you store your data in a nested dictionary?

```
subject={'INF': {"INFO100":"A", "INFO200":"B"},
         'OTH': {"OTHER100":"C", "OTHER200":"D"},
         }
```

Then access:

```
# all subitems
subject['INF']

# given item
subject['INF']['INFO100']
```

Answer (score 1):

For understanding porpoises, you can create a function that returns a dictionary, like:

```
def getGradesBySubject(dict, search_subject):
    return [grade for subject,grade in dict.iteritems() if subject.startwith(search_subject)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a master `dict` object that contains a mapping of the three-letter subjects like ECO, GEO, to all subject values. For example:

```py
subject = {"INFO100": "A",
           "INFO200": "B",
           "GEO100": "D",
           "ECO101": "B",
           "GEO003": "C",
           "INFO101": "C"}

master_dict = {}
for k, v in subject.items():
    master_dict.setdefault(k[:3], []).append(v)

print(master_dict)
# now you can access it like: master_dict['INF']
```

Output:

```
{'INF': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'GEO': ['D', 'C'], 'ECO': ['B']}
```

---

If you want to eliminate duplicate grades for a subject, or just as an alternate approach, I'd also suggest a `defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

subject = {"INFO100": "A",
           "INFO300": "A",
           "INFO200": "B",
           "GEO100": "D",
           "ECO101": "B",
           "GEO003": "C",
           "GEO102": "D",
           "INFO101": "C"}

master_dict = defaultdict(set)
for k, v in subject.items():
    master_dict[k[:3]].add(v)

print(master_dict)
```

```
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'INF': {'B', 'A', 'C'}, 'GEO': {'D', 'C'}, 'ECO': {'B'}})
```